# MySQL RAND() not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run the following query using phpMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE TABLE x SET `number` = RAND();
```

I want to add a random value to each row but it's giving me an error.

My idea is to try to put random values between 10 and 30 in the whole thing, so I'm trying something like this as well:

```
UPDATE TABLE x SET `number` = 10 + (30-10)*RAND();
```

Sorry for the noob question! And thank you!

Comment: Telling us which error it's giving you would be helpful.  We're note very keen on guessing.

Comment: Doesn't help much: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE x SET `number` = RAND()' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the TABLE keyword.

```
UPDATE x SET number = 10 + (30-10)*RAND();
```

x being the name of the table

Comment: thanks :) I just want to say thanks why do i need to write more!